# Extract numbers from a string in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract only area numbers from a column in pandas dataframe : 568 sq mi (1,471 km2) here I only want 568 the space between the number and sq is unbreakable space.

Comment: `I only want 568 the space between the number and sq is unbreakable space.` what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

you can probably do this

```
df[col].apply(lambda x:x[:3])
```

this will extract the starting number for the whole column, change the df with your data frame name and col with your column name

Comment: Thank you so much, but this column in the dataframe has two more values that includes periods or commas the two other values are  1,179 sq mi
(3,054 km2) and  61.9 sq mi
(160 km2)

Comment: you can find the mentioned table in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Missouri

Comment: for that, you can use this, although there must be some greater solution this might get the work done.

df[col].apply(lambda x:x.split("sq")[0].replace(" ",""))
(replace name with your df and col with your col)

Answer (score 0):

So try using regex on the string.

Eg :

```
import re
str = "568.78 sq mi (1,471 km2)"
num = re.findall(r"[0-9]+", str)
print(num[0])
```

Output :

```
568.78
```

Since its on the columns of dataframe try something like this.

```
def fmt(row):
   number = re.findall(r"[0-9,.]+",row)
   return number[0]

numbers = list(map(fmt,df[col]))
df['fmt area'] = numbers
```

Think this should work.

Comment: Thank you so much, but this column in the dataframe has two more values that includes periods or commas the two other values are  1,179 sq mi
(3,054 km2) and  61.9 sq mi
(160 km2)

Comment: you can find the mentioned table in this link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_in_Missouri

Comment: Change the regex to 

r"[0-9,.]"

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .str method and use extract and pass regular expression pattern.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"Area":["568 sq mi (1,471 km2)"]})

df["area changed"] = df.Area.str.extract(r"(\d+ \w+)")
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Thank you so much, but this column in the dataframe has two more values that includes periods or commas the two other values are  1,179 sq mi
(3,054 km2) and  61.9 sq mi
(160 km2)